Use SqlConnection created by .NET Aspire in another project
A .NET Aspire application (net8.0, Aspire 8) has configured a SQL Server Container in the AppHost.
In a web app's Program.cs the builder.AddSqlServerClient("mySqlServer") registers a SqlConnection factory with the dependency injection container. After adding a SqlConnection, you can get the scoped SqlConnection instance using DI.
I can use this SqlConnection directly in the same project but I'm using a data repository project to separate concerns (not EF Core but Dapper instead). The data repository is available from the web project via DI:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();

Can the SqlConnection in the web app's DI container from the .AddSqlServer() be passed along to the scoped IDataRepository? How would this be done?
At the moment in the DataRepository implementation I use the connection string from the environment variables to create a SqlConnection object but I'd prefer to use the SqlConnection created by .AddSqlServer() as it's already been configured by the Aspire ServiceDefaults.

AZURE has a Front End and Back End.  Front End is an HTTP client to Server Connection.  Back End is a connection between Server and Database.  The Server is the Web project.  So your project is a client and needs to make a HTTP connection to the Aspire Project.  How do you presently connect to the Aspire Project?  Are you using a Browser?  There are a lot of different was of making an HTTP connection from c# and getting back a response.

i imagine if you have a SqlConnection constructor parameter for DataRepository that should be resolved automatically

You can walk up to the app's IConfiguration and request the connection string directly. For example:
public class DataRepository(IConfiguration config)
{
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string id)
    {
        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("mySqlServer");
        // TODO: Use the connection string here...
    }
}

I made some assumptions about the DataRepository class, but the idea is the same regardless of where you call GetConnectionString.
